C# Program to run rxvt command
I'm in a weird situation where I have a computer that only runs the commands I need if I run them through a special type of command window.  I've found the shortcut to bring up that cygwin terminal is:
rxvt -ls
That shortcut gives me a new terminal that runs the commands I want properly,  but I'd have to type them by hand that's not what I'm wanting,  I want to automate things that I need to do in there.  I have a C# program that I'm trying to use that ability to run those commands hundreds of times for data collection.
The closest cmd.exe test command I can find is this:
rxvt -ls -e sh -c ls >> output.txt
I figured if I could output each command to hundreds of files i could at least be in business.  I would then replace the ls with the command I need to get the info I need.
This makes a window pop up for a second then go away.  No output file with the output appears.

So, now we know what doesn't work. But still we have no clue what you are trying to do. How can we suggest solutions? I am relatively confident there are ways to get a c#-canonical equivalent of an "ls" command, for example.

I have a computer from a customer,  that uses Cygwin.  They have commands that only work when you run their custom terminal (rxvt).  If I try these commands on a simple command line it doesn’t know them.I’d like to build a c# program to run those commands,  but I can’t find a way to send the commands and get the results from those commands.  I don’t get their rxvt terminal they use.

Then maybe add those commands to your question. Rxvt is a well known Linux terminal emulator, so the commands are probably just Linux / Gnu commands.

It won't mean anything to you or 99.999% of the internet,  it's made by someone else and not a common command line command.  When I try to run it in windows command line it just says access denied.
That's why I replaced the example with "ls".   A common command we all know that returns useful information.

In that case, SO cannot help. You need to consult the manual of that command or contact the author of that command.

This is pseudo code of what I would want to do.  I apologize but the spacing doesn't seem to keep when I submit this.
foreach(var thingIwantInfoOn in things) {
   // Run Command from C# that somehow gets that custom command that only seems to work through their rxvt command line

 //  If I could pass something in like this
 // On their rxvt terminal,  it's simple,  something like qls thing
 // I just can't get that command to work programatically though,  was hoping if I can pass parameters into cmd.exe or rxvt and print or return the info I'd be good.

}

You can start Processes from C#/.Net, pass paramaters to them and read their StdOut / StdErr ... Either with plain Process or one of the convenience libraries that make that a little easier. example of that

I finally got it to work.  This post had a solution that worked for me.  I obviously don't fully understand what happens but oh well,  I got a result.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46387583/how-to-execute-a-cygwin-command-from-c-sharp-and-leave-it-open

Would you consider the other one a "duplicate"?

Not quite,  I changed gears and tried a different route that he did.  I appreciate you guys trying to help,  I know this wasn't the clearest question in the world.
